# Send data from Service to Widget on Android

Tags: java, android

I am writing a widget on Android 1.6 that shows the minutes that a person has used on the current month.
The way I have it setup is by having a service that listens to the state of the phone and when  the phone is picked up, it starts the timer and when the person hangs up, ends a timer. I would like to send this variable(long duration) over to my appWidgetProvider so I could update the edit text on it.

Answer (score 0):

I'm no expert, but the AppWidgetProvider is the one that starts the service, right? Why not simply give a reference to the AppWidgetProvider upon creation of the service?